# Elasticsearch configuration for test environment

Tags: elasticsearch, integration-testing, virtualbox, vagrant

We are doing automated integration testings between our application and Elasticsearch and we would like to get better performance with while running our tests.

We have a script to run our tests and before each tests it deletes all indices and then run a bulk to populate the indices.

Here's our Elasticsearch config

```
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0
index.refresh_interval: 50
index.store.type: memory
```

The bottle neck of our tests is the before each instruction which take ~0.7s each time.

Is there some configurations we should change or add ?

Thanks for the help.

Elasticsearch is running inside Virtualbox using vagrant (If this can be of any help).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by stubbing responses from elasticsearch for tests that not relates to search.

For example we don't need to create index if we don't test search features.

Comment: That's what we are doing with our unit tests... But in our integration/system tests with want to make sure that everything is working together and since the main feature of our api is the search capabilities ... We kind a need to test the search and create the index. Of course we could separate as much as possible the tests and for all the search, indexing only once...